# How to extract date parts from text string in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a column called event_time with the date & time in the following format:
2020-04-24 11:50:39 UTC

I'm trying to extract different parts of the date, such as year, using the following query:

```
SELECT event_time, strftime('%y',event_time) AS year
```

But the result is NULL. I've tried formatting the column as both TEXT and NUMERIC with no luck. Is the "UTC" preventing it from being recognized as a date? What is the best way to extract dates and times that I can work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove the `UTC` suffix and use `%Y` instead of `%y` as the format of [`strftime()`](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
strftime('%Y', SUBSTR('2020-04-24 11:50:39 UTC', 1, 19)) AS year
```

or:

```
strftime('%Y', REPLACE('2020-04-24 11:50:39 UTC', 'UTC', ''))
```

return `2020`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=1f5e75736ca28a7d4449ba6db56ad770).